# How to deal best with attitudes of a new user?

Tags: discussion, comments, new-users

I came across [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27278927/string-multiple-replacement-of-strings-in-text), tried to compile the code sample given and miserably failed. Also editing out the obvious errors didn't help much, and I decided it's not worth it to dig further this way, since the OP even doesn't state what the concrete errors are (e.g. compiler errors, unexpected output, runtime errors etc.).

I've been placing a quick comment asking for probabply one of the most obvious errors in that code (even if it would have compiled).

Now the user asking this question just tries to chase me away with unconstructive comments, instead of taking my hints (well the technical, as those for SO policies too).

How should we best deal with such (I've been trying to keep polite and professional with my follow up comments).

Comment: [How to resolve a comment war about a disagreement](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/278351/how-to-resolve-a-comment-war-about-a-disagreement)

Comment: @bummi I'm not sure this is already a _comment war_. I'm not planning to give further comments on the question, and I have flagged that unconstructive comments of course as such.

Comment: Just my impressions: your excessive use of bold, exclamation points, and doubled question marks makes your comments seem a bit...aggressive. It actually seems like you overreacted.

Comment: Downvote.  Vote to close.  Move on.

Comment: @bummi That's a radically different situation from this one.

Comment: @Will Usually I'm doing so, but being pinged :-P ...

Comment: They will eventually stop.  If not, flag for mod attention.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ  you can delete your comments if you really want; as that would prevent replies to you.

Comment: @ThisSuitIsBlackNot What's wrong with emphasis? I don't think I've been overreacting actually. All I tried was to be helpful, to push the OP into the right direction how to improve the question.

Comment: @Servy I would not have seen as duplicate, but the strategy respect of argumentation might be very familiar

Comment: @bummi A user refusing to add the required information to their question is radically different from someone providing an answer that you think is wrong and not editing their posts in response to your statement's that it's wrong.  The situations are different, how they're handled is different, there just isn't much at all that overlaps between the two.  That question is about a polite, constructive, but lengthy debate over the merits of an answer.  This is an unconstructive, insulting, and inappropriate discussion involving making a question answerable.

Comment: That was definitely a comment war.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In general, if you encounter rude or unconstructive comments, flag them and moderators will clean up as necessary. I've done that here.

However, I preserved the comment thread below for discussion:

[image: Comment thread in question]

Your comment of

> `std::string.erase(`?? Really?

does come off a little strong. I can see how someone might read that as being a little mocking. D Drmmr's follow-on comment after that was outright insulting, which might have primed them for being angry in their response.

I should point out that you were the one who prolonged the comment thread by leaving comments like "Don't tell me now to comment on your question" and "You are wasting my and other users time". Those weren't particularly helpful and I would not classify them as polite.

If you do not believe a user has invested sufficient effort in their question, downvote, vote to close, and/or leave a polite comment suggesting ways they can improve it. Carrying on an argument isn't particularly helpful.

Comment: THX! Yeah, your interactions fixed it, it looks like now. Seems I had my _"bad hair day"_ with this OP.

Comment: I'd have the same reaction if I tried to help out a clueless user with active actions (go to ideone, try to compile, then come back commenting) with having this reply "keep this sort of comments for yourself"...

Answer (score 4):

Being completely honest, I find your comments to HankMoody a little harsh, callous in some ways, and certainly opposing from the start - for no good reason.
And you were quite pushy in *telling* the OP what to should do - rather than *advising* them.

With this standoffish scenario between you and the OP, there is not much chance of them taking your advice, giving you feedback on them trying it or explaining why it is not necessary etc, and then you advising further.

I know there are many new users who dump their poorly written and badly formatted code which doesn't work, turn their back, and ask someone else to sort it, write them the working resolve, and explain what is wrong.
And I know how it feels to get sick and tired of this, especially when usually they get a (bloody) answer as well!
But there is nothing you can do about it other than use the tools provided - comments, votes, flags, or leaving the question alone.

So if you are correct in your observations in their code won't even compile, then politely tell them this, and that they should resolve such issues before trying to resolve functionality issues within the code itself.

If they do not listen to your advice, then move on to someone who you can help.
Downvote and/or flag (unclear what asking etc) where required/applicable, and move on to another question where you *can* help someone.

> You can lead a horse to water, but you can't make him drink.

---

Have a read through your comments as if they are someone else's, not yours, and see if you can see the wording and approach is a little *sharp*:
(Use of bold, double exclamation marks, telling OP what to do, not advising, standoffish - "don't tell me not to comment" - a little demanding in parts)

> `std::string.erase(`?? Really`?
>
> Ehh what please?? You are in charge to provide a MCVE in 1st place!!
>   Or give us a clear questions about the compiler error messages you
>   get, to get a reasonable answer for your problems. Don't tell me not
>   to comment on your question, as long you're not in the position to
>   have a valid question asked, or find a valid reason to flag my
>   comment!
>
> You are wasting my and other users time actually, while I took the
>   time trying to get your code to compile! Even if I remove the
>   std::string::erase there are so many errors in your code (e.g.
>   std::string.begin(), std::string.end() should be actually
>   str1.begin(), str1.end(), aso.). Either provide a valid sample as
>   mentioned in the link I gave you (compilable sample), or ask about
>   these compiler errors (include verbatim into your question), and how
>   you could fix them in 1st place.
>
> BTW what's an "EOT"? And I also believe, you have "to get" something
>   more, about how the site works: Help Center)

Answer (score 2):

If the question isn't answerable due to a lack of information, vote to close accordingly, and downvote the question.

If the user isn't interested in improving the question to make it answerable, then the question is likely to end up being deleted by the roomba.  If he decides to improve the question to add the necessary information, it may end up being reopened and answered.